# using C# OpenXml SDK apply strike through for all bullets in MS Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I need to apply styles to bullets in a `MS Word` document.
I am able to read full `docx` using `OpenXML` then apply styles for Paragraphs using `Run` nodes

[image]

This is how I am applying styles at other areas based up on the condition

```
private void StrikeAndUnderline(Run run)
        {
            if (run.RunProperties == null)
            {
                run.RunProperties = new RunProperties();
            }
            run.RunProperties.Strike = new Strike();
            run.RunProperties.Strike.Val = true;
            run.RunProperties.Underline = new Underline();
            run.RunProperties.Underline.Val = UnderlineValues.Single;
        }
```

But I don't get a `Run` property for bullets

[image]

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
    <w:numPr>
      <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
      <w:numId w:val="1"/>
    </w:numPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Paragraph one.</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the explanation @Shelest provided, here is the quick & dirty implementation of striking bullets using OpenXML SDK

```
public static void ReadAndStrikeBulletsWithOpenXml()
        {
            var sourcePath = @"C:\temp\test.docx";
            var destinationPath = @"C:\temp\new-test.docx";
            File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);
            using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destinationPath, true))
            {
                Numbering numbering = document.MainDocumentPart.NumberingDefinitionsPart.Numbering;
                var abstractNum = numbering.ChildElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LocalName.Equals("abstractNum"));
                if (abstractNum?.ChildElements != null)
                {
                    foreach (var child in abstractNum.ChildElements)
                    {
                        if (child.OuterXml.Contains("<w:lvl"))
                        {
                            XmlDocument levelXml = new XmlDocument();
                            levelXml.LoadXml(child.OuterXml);

                            XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(levelXml.NameTable);
                            namespaceManager.AddNamespace("w",
                                "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

                            XmlNode runProperty = levelXml.SelectSingleNode("w:lvl/w:rPr", namespaceManager);
                            if (runProperty == null)
                            {
                                // Need to uncomment this if you prefer to strike all bullets at all levels
                                //child.InnerXml = child.InnerXml +
                                //                 "<w:rPr><w:strike w:val\"1\"/></w:rPr>";
                            }
                            else if (runProperty.InnerXml.Contains("w:strike"))
                            {
                                XmlDocument runXml = new XmlDocument();
                                runXml.LoadXml(runProperty.OuterXml);

                                XmlNamespaceManager runNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(runXml.NameTable);
                                runNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("w",
                                    "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

                                XmlNode strikeNode = runXml.SelectSingleNode("w:rPr/w:strike", namespaceManager);
                                if (strikeNode?.Attributes != null)
                                {
                                    if (strikeNode.Attributes["w:val"] == null)
                                    {
                                        // do nothing
                                    }
                                    else if (strikeNode.Attributes["w:val"].Value == "0")
                                    {
                                        child.InnerXml = child.InnerXml.Replace("w:strike w:val=\"0\"", "w:strike w:val=\"1\"");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
                document.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious, but Document part contains only reference to numbering unit (with all formatting and numbering styles) which stores in Numbering part.

--Document part.
So in Document part you have to grub both NumberingLevelReference(w:ilvl) and NumberingId(w:numId).

--Numbering part.
The next step is open Numbering part and search for NumberingInstance(w:num) with NumberID property that is the same as NumberingId you see in Document part.
Now once you have desired NumberingInstance, look for AbstractNumId among it's children and remember it's value. 
Now search for AbstractNum node with same Id you just remembered.

Cheers! Now you have Properties of you current numbering. The properties are separated by numbering levels. So now search for desired level(), the one you saw in numbering properties in Document part.
Once you find node that means right numbering level you should make it something like

```
<w:lvl w:ilvl="0" w:tplc="BBD6A362" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:start w:val="1" />
  <w:numFmt w:val="decimal" />
  <w:lvlText w:val="%1." />
  <w:lvlJc w:val="left" />
  <w:pPr>
    <w:ind w:left="720" w:hanging="360" />
  </w:pPr>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:strike />
  </w:rPr>
</w:lvl>
```

Comment: When I load MainDocument from OpenXml SDK I don't get numbering part, do I need to explicitly do something to get this object constructed?

Comment: @HaBo be sure your document contains numbering to be striked first.

Comment: how do I make sure of that? I load the XML from docx path.

Comment: @HaBo , I gave you whole the workflow, just try to think further or manage to learn some OpenXml basics, it will be very beneficial to you.